# CDialogEx:: OnNCPaint() increases the size of dialog window

Tags: mfc, custom-titlebar, custom-draw, onncpaint

I need to draw custom title bar, using Win10, VS2017, MFC, SDK10.0.16299.0.

When `MyDialog::OnNcPaint()` does not call `CDialogEx::OnNcPaint()`, the dialog frame is drawn incorrectly - the top corners are rounded while bottom corners are sharp, and dialog size increases in couple of pixels.

I need to keep the dialog in original size and shape. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Any reason you can't just draw your custom frame over the top of the one drawn by `CDialogEx::OnNcPaint()`?

Comment: I can only paint to NC area when base class is not called. When I call CDialogEx::OnNcPaint() inside of MyDialogEx::OnNcPaint() (even at first line), then my custom draw is not painted at all.

Comment: Using `WM_NCPAINT` is deprecated as it doesn't work well together with DWM (desktop window manager). Use [DWM functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe) instead to draw custom title bar on recent Windows versions.